# Armazenar / Carregar tipos genéricos no Redis com C#

Tags: c#, cache, redis

**Cenário**

Criei uma função usando AOP para fazer Cache de informações, quando o método é chamado eu armazeno no Redis utilizando o `cache.StringSet`, porém quando preciso capturar de volta o valor do Redis preciso que volte do mesmo tipo que eu recebi, não sei se estou fazendo da forma correta serializando e armazenando a string, mas quando eu retornar do Redis `cache.StringGet` preciso que seja do mesmo tipo quando o objeto foi inserido.
Lembrando que os objetos podem variar, podem ser de N tipos diferentes.

**Código**

```
public sealed override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
{
    var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
    var result = cache.StringGet(args.Method.Name);

    if (result.HasValue)
    {
        args.ReturnValue = result;
        return;
    }

    base.OnInvoke(args);
    cache.StringSet(args.Method.Name, Serialize(args.ReturnValue));
}

private string Serialize(object obj)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contornei o problema com a seguinte solução:

No método de entrada onde tenho o Aspecto mudei os tipos para `dynamic`.
Sendo assim a entrada e saída é genérica, utilizando `object` também funcionou.
Por enquanto manterei dessa forma.

```
[RedisCacheableResult]
public List<dynamic> ReturnCustomer()
{
    var lstCustomer = new List<dynamic>();

    var customer = new Customer
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Acme Inc",
        Email = "acme@email.com"
    };

    var customer1 = new Customer
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Marvel Inc",
        Email = "Marvel@email.com"
    };

    lstCustomer.Add(customer);
    lstCustomer.Add(customer1);

    return lstCustomer;
}
```

No Deserialize utilizo:

```
private static dynamic Deserialize(string data)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(data, Settings);
}
```

Segue a solução publicada no **GitHub**:
https://github.com/thiagoloureiro/TestaCache

Issues, pullrequests, stars e forks são bem vindos :)